# When I toggle the picture the font awesome icon is not showing. How can I resolve this?

Tags: reactjs

What I want to do is when I click the picture icons will appear. Blank circles is appearing when I toggle.

```
const [classList, setClassList] = useState("menu-hidden");
 //const [isToggle, setIsToggle] = useState(false);
setTimeout(() => {
    setClassList("menu");
  }, 2000);

  const circularButton = () => {
    //setIsToggle(!isToggle);
    //console.log(isToggle);
    classList === "menu" ? setClassList("menu active") : setClassList("menu");
  };
  const iZero =
    '<li style="--i: 0"><i style="color:#333;" class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>';
 
  

<div className={classList}>
            <div className="toggle" onClick={circularButton}>
              <img src={Picture} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div
              className="div"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: iZero }}
            ></div>
    </div>
```